# RPC deadline exceeded.: Backend timeout

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Getting the error as

```
"responses": [
    {
        "error": {
            "code": 4,
            "message": "image-annotator::RPC deadline exceeded.: Backend timeout!"
         }
    }
]
```

while trying to use OCR through vision APIs